# load huge pdf in javascript pdf viewer

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have this 250Mb pdf which I would like to view in a browser using javascript.
I'm using [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). The problem is that I would like to show this pdf also on mobile devices. I noticed that it takes a long time to load (and finally the browser crashed). Is there something that I can do to make this smarter, for example only load the page I want to see. For example the code I have now looks like this:

```
var url = '/data/huge.pdf';
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {         
    pdf.getPage(8).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
    var scale = 1;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

    page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
});
});
```

In this example I want to display page 8. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Pretty sure you're not going to be able to pull this one off. 250mb being pushed into browser memory does not go well. Ever. You're better off using a backend service to split the pages apart, then request the page you want.

Comment: I don't think users are going to be happy if they have to download a PDF of 250mB's on their mobile device.. But like Stephen set above, if you can use a backend service to split the pages, this will reduce.

Comment: I get the impression that this demo does show the first pages while loading the rest: [demo](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)

Comment: It seems that the backend splits the pdf into single pages